# Get div html with select value of dynamically created select in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I dynamically created a div with select options in jQuery. Here's a sample.

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option selected value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
        <option value="2">C</option>
        <option value="3">D</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

0 is the default selected value.

When I get html of the div like this `$("#myDiv").html()`, it gets the below.

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <select id="mySelect">
        <option selected value="0">A</option>
        <option value="1">B</option>
        <option value="2">C</option>
        <option value="3">D</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

It's the same as the above code which is normal.

However, when I change the selected value to 2, `$("#myDiv").html()` is still getting same code. 0 is still the selected value.

How can I get the html of the div, with the dynamically changed value?

Comment: Why do you need the html?  If you need the value, get the value.  The "html" doesn't change.  The DOM does.

Comment: Also, your question is slightly inaccurate.  Based on the markup you have given, `$('#myDiv').html()` would *not* return that entire html structure, as `html()` only returns the innerHTML, not the outerHTML, so it would only return the select, not the outer div that was the element selected.

Comment: @Taplar Because I will get the html and I will add some html to it and get the html again.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this :

```
$('#yourSelect option:selected').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#myDiv').find("#mySelect").change(function () {
    alert($("#mySelect option:selected").text());
    alert($("#mySelect option:selected").val());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
function create_select(){
    var select=$('<select/>').attr('id','mySelect');
    var option0=$('<option/>').val(0).text('A').attr('selected', true);
       select.append(option0);
    var option1=$('<option/>').val(1).text('B');
      select.append(option1);
    var option2=$('<option/>').val(2).text('C');
      select.append(option2);
    var option3=$('<option/>').val(3).text('D');
      select.append(option3);
    $('#myDiv').empty().append(select);
}


function change_select_value(_new_val){
 $('#mySelect option').removeAttr('selected');
 $('#mySelect').val(_new_val).change();
}


$(document).on('change', '#mySelect', function(){    //conctruction for Dynamically created element
        alert('change value to =>'+this.value);  //or  $(this).val();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDiv"></div>
<input type="button" value="Create Select" onclick="create_select();" /></br>
<input type="button" value="Set option C (value=2)" onclick="change_select_value(2);" /></br>
```